# How to enable/disable VoiceOver speech programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover

Is it possible to enable/disable VoiceOver speech/spoken hints on all items/entirely temporarily? In our App, we have a recording function and VoiceOver doesn't stop talking during recording and the speech gets recorded.

I would like to know if there is a way.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`startsMediaSession` trait](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitytraits/1620173-startsmediasession) on the button that starts the recording , which will tell VoiceOver to stop announcing its speech output while the recording is being made.

```
myButton.accessibilityTraits.insert(.startsMediaSession)
```

> Use this trait to silence the audio output of an assistive app, such as VoiceOver, during a media session that you don't want to interrupt. For example, you might use this trait to silence VoiceOver speech while the user is recording audio.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't achieve above, but wrote a workaround. It no longer announces when recording is started (or when we enter recording view) but still works if user one presses a button.

```swift
// We want to avoid automatic VoiceOver announcement in this view
// Otherwise it's announced during recording
let decoyView = UIView()
decoyView.isAccessibilityElement = true
decoyView.accessibilityTraits = .none
    
// Order accessibility elements, VoiceOver announces first element due to auto focus
self.view.accessibilityElements = [decoyView, yourViewItems]
```

The problem happened because when user presses Record, the app enters a new view, which VoiceOver automatically focuses the first accessibility element in that view.

Comment: If a new view is being displayed when the recording starts, your hack may be your best option, although it is not ideal to confuse screen reader users with an accessibilityElement that does nothing.